# How to get a command to appear in right-click menu in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, contextmenu, right-click

How can I get a command found in the standard menu of the IDE to also appear in the right-click context menu in VS2005?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this if its any help to you:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
    _application = (DTE2)application;
    if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)
    {
    // Other command bars are: "Code Window", "ASPX Code Context"
        var commandBar = _application.CommandBars["ASPX Context"];

        CommandBarButton test =
                commandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true) as CommandBarButton;

            // Set the caption of the submenuitem
            test.Caption = "Edit";
            test.Enabled = true;
            test.Visible = true;
            test.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(MyEventHandler);
    }
}
```